# Proper syntax for passing array to function

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

if I declare an array with something like this:

```
const char var[]="Some message here";
```

and then have a function that prints this message by accepting a pointer to the array like this:

```
void printMessage(char *msg)
```

Then what is the difference if I call this function like this:

`printMessage(var);`

or this:

`printMessage(&var[0]);`

and which is the more proper way of calling this function?

Comment: Both are equal, but the first is less to write (and the most commonly used).

Comment: In fact you *can't* pass an array to a function; you can only pass a pointer to an array's first element (or, less commonly, a pointer to the whole array). Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it explains the often confusing relationship between C arrays and pointers very well.

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is no difference -- `var` is the literal equivalent of `&var[0]`

Which one to use is part personal preference, part readability and part consistency. If, for example, you're going to call the function at one point with `var` and at another point with `&var[n]` then I would argue to use `&var[0]` in the first call as a readability aid.

Comment: They're equivalent in this context. They're quite different as, for example, an argument to `sizeof`.

Comment: Granted... but the questions was very specifically about passing arrays to functions, not generic array references. Though, I'll admit, it's easy to mistake `sizeof()` for a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Both `var` and `&var[0]` equal the address of the first member in the char array.

The former is simplest for arrays.

The latter can be useful for passing a std::vector to a function that accepts an array address.

Answer (score 0):

They are identical in C.  If you have a C-array or a C-pointer, use the shorter syntax.

I use the longer syntax when dealing with vectors in c++, to make it clear exactly what is happening:

```
void f(const double * arry);
void g() {
    std::vector<double> vec = //.....
    f(&(vec[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like that, I simply pass `var`, but when I'm doing pointer arithmetic, I use the longer form of `&var[3]` instead of `var + 3` because I think it makes it more clear that I'm doing pointer arithmetic.